# Group b Time and return Boolean value if group contain

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have df as below.

```
Index                                Receiver     
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000         R1          
1970-01-01 00:00:00.800000000         R1          
1970-01-01 00:00:01.000287000         R2          
1970-01-01 00:00:01.600896000         R2          
1970-01-01 00:00:02.001388000         R1          
1970-01-01 00:00:02.004698000         R1          
1970-01-01 00:00:02.006706000         R2          
1970-01-01 00:00:02.501351000         R2          
1970-01-01 00:00:02.810382000         R2          
1970-01-01 00:00:03.001981000         R1          
1970-01-01 00:00:03.377116000         R1          
1970-01-01 00:00:03.701811000         R2          
1970-01-01 00:00:03.910326000         R2          
1970-01-01 00:00:03.951355000         R2
```

How to get the following df from above?

```
Index                        R1   R2  
1970-01-01 00:00:00          1    0   
1970-01-01 00:00:01          0    1   
1970-01-01 00:00:02          1    1   
1970-01-01 00:00:03          1    1
```

Appreciate one liner code. 
Regards,
Asif

Comment: next time, don't forget to include your effort and how you want to approach to the result. It bit ambiguous to know how you want to do it. Creating a new dataframe with those values is also a possible solution. Hope you get it.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use pivot_table with aggfunc `size` and then convert `notnull()` values to int i.e

```
df.pivot_table(index = pd.Grouper(key='Index',freq='s'),columns='Receiver',aggfunc='size').notnull().astype(int)

Receiver                R1 R2
Index                        
1970-01-01 00:00:00      1  0
1970-01-01 00:00:01      0  1
1970-01-01 00:00:02      1  1
1970-01-01 00:00:03      1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.set_index('Index').Receiver.resample('S').apply(lambda x : ','.join(set(x))).str.get_dummies(sep=',')
Out[909]: 
                     R1  R2
Index                      
1970-01-01 00:00:00   1   0
1970-01-01 00:00:01   0   1
1970-01-01 00:00:02   1   1
1970-01-01 00:00:03   1   1
```

Comment: @Dark just pd.Serise get_dummy :-)

Comment: Dear Wen, Your answer is correct, but @Dark replied first so I am marking his answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MuhammadAsifKhan no worry ,as long as it help :-)

Comment: @MuhammadAsifKhan its not about who posted first, its about how elegant the solution is. I dont have any problem if you accept this solution.